# GMap.NET 1.7 Exception Throw

Tags: c#, gmap.net

Currently, I'm using GMap.NET (1.7 version) for C# with Visual Studio 2008.
It works fine, however, I'm not able to run my winform app any more.

I'm getting this error when firing `InitializeComponent()` for my form. The type initializer for `GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl` throws an exception.

If I revert back to 1.6 version, it works fine.

Is there anybody who knows this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

Download precompiled binaries for your .NET version from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/99229e8a9f2b2617).
Extract package and copy System.Data.SQLite.dll near your exe (\bin\Debug or Release).

You can simply add it in your project with "Copy to output dir: copy always". **DO NOT reference DLL file!**

Comment: Thanks. It seemed to be related with SQLITE version. If I set to x86, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problems recently. But my project had to be a x64-solution. The following worked for me, maybe it will help you, too.

If you download the GMap.Net-Sources, you can build an "AnyCode"-Version of the Library. You normally (if you only use the WindowsForms-Component) don't need to recompile everything, for me it was enough to recompile GMap.Net.Core and GMap.Net.WindowsForms.

Then you can reference the newly compiled dlls in your project. The Winforms-Designer will be using the x86-variant, your program, when you decide to build for x64 only, will use the x64-version.

You have to manually copy the SQLite.Interop-dlls into %SOLUTION%/bin/Release|Debug/x64 and x86 - x64 and x86 are subfolders of the Release/Debug folder.

If you have a setup-project in your solution, these dlls have to be manually put into the same folders inside the "Application Folder". The dependency for System.Data.SQLite and the manually added GMap-Dlls will be automatically set by the Setup-Project (maybe you have to do a refresh dependencies), as they are dependencies of the GMap-Components.